# Sending variable and image via ajax

Tags: html, ajax, jscript

Could anybody please help me with this as i have tried several different methods all to no avail.

im trying to send the old image src name along with the new image data via ajax, but i can only manage to send 1 or the other and not both..

```
file = input.files[0];
newimagesrc=input.files[0].name;
oldimagesrc=oldsrc;     

formData= new FormData();
formData.append("image", file , newimagesrc);

recent attempt failed formData2= new FormData();                                                                                   
recent attempt failed formdata2.append('oldimage', oldimagesrc);                                                                                  

$.ajax({
url: "UploadProfileImage.php",                                                                                   
type: "POST",                                                                                    
data: formData,                                                                                  
processData: false,                                                                                  
contentType: false,

success: function(messagereturn1){
alert(messagereturn1);
}

});
```

No buttons or forms im afraid, strictly passing variable's onchange / onclick.

Not sure how to send the old image src through ajax as well as the new image data , i would like to send more variables if possible that have been passed into JS function..

Answer (score 0):

```
var form_data = new FormData(); // Creating object of FormData class

form_data.append("image", file , newimagesrc) // Appending image parameter

form_data.append("oldimagesrc", oldimagesrc) //added a second variable then received in PHP as a $_POST['oldimagesrc']
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['oldimagesrc'])){ $oldimagesrc=$_POST['oldimagesrc']; }
```